# CIS benchmark: How to define the BUILTIN\Administrator account within GPOs?

Tags: group-policy, security

I am responsible for configuring GPOs according to the latest CIS benchmark policy. However the test for "Impersonate a client after authentication" always fails, although everything seems to be configured correctly.

```
Computer Configuration => Policies => Windows Settings => Security Settings => Local Policies => User Rights Assignment => Impersonate a client after authentication
```

This setting above contains:

- Administrators
- LOCAL SERVICE
- NETWORK SERVICE
- SERVICE

This of course doesn't match the regex used by Tripwire (according to the report).

```
"^\s*BUILTIN\\Administrators,\s+NT\s+AUTHORITY\\LOCAL\s+SERVICE,\s+NT\s+AUTHORITY\\NETWORK\s+SERVCE,\s+NT\s+AUTHORITY\\SERVICE\s*$"
```

If I however replace "Administrator" with "BUILTIN\Administrator" the GPMC console complains with the following:

```
Administrators and SERVICE must be granted the impersonate client after authentication privileve.
```

The question is now: **Am I providing the correct string to the GPO or needs the regex a correction?**

Comment: Well, "BUILTIN" means the local machine, so "Administrators" should match that. Maybe add the account to the Administrators group?

Comment: Okay, that implies the string "Administrators" is equal to "BUILTIN\Administrators" and therefor the regex needs to be corrected.